# glassfish 3.1.1 'unique' JNI error

Tags: java-native-interface, glassfish-3

A webapp using native code works fine in Glassfish 2.x.

In 3.1.1, it fails with:

```
[#|2012-04-18T14:43:08.330+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.basistech.rnt.jni.initializeEnvironmentSpecificRootDirectory(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at com.basistech.rnt.jni.initializeEnvironmentSpecificRootDirectory(Native Method)
```

Note that this is the version of the linkage error that complains about a particular symbol, not about the entire library.

The very same JNI lib works fine run from a sample Java program *outside* of Glassfish on the very same machine.

Reading the JDK source, this would seem to be possible only if `dlsym` (we're on Linux) fails to return the symbol. (This is all Java 1.6.x.) I'm stumped as to what Glassfish could possibly be doing that would cause `dlsym` to fail to see this symbol in the shared lib.

Any ideas out there?